# Integral $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^7x \cos^5x\, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

im asked to find the limited integral here but unfortunately im floundering can someone please point me in the right direction?
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^7x \cos^5x\, dx $$

**step 1** brake up sin and cos so that i can use substitution
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^7(x) \cos^4(x) \cos(x) \, dx$$
**step 2** apply trig identity
 $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^7x\ (1-\sin^2 x)^2 \, dx$$
**step 3** use $u$-substitution
$$ \text{let}\,\,\, u= \sin(x)\ du=\cos(x)   $$
**step 4** apply use substitution
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} u^7 (1-u^2)^2 du $$
**step 5** expand and distribute and change limits of integration
     $$\int_0^1 u^7-2u^9+u^{11}\ du $$ 
**step 6** integrate
$$(1^7-2(1)^9+1^{11})-0$$
i would just end up with $1$ however the book answer is $$\frac {1}{120}$$

how can i be so far off?

Comment: Where are your differentials?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you actually took the antiderivative from step 5 to step 6

Comment: OMG i feel so stupid right now. Long day guys ive been looking at this for too long. My apologies. thanks for pointing out my dumb mistake.

Comment: Style protip: Fractions $\frac ab$ in integral bounds can become difficult to read; consider using $a/b$ instead. See [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/43351) for more (Math.SE-specific) TeX tips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin^7x\cos^5xdx=\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin^7x\cos^4x\cos xdx=\int_0^\frac\pi2\sin^7x(1-\sin^2x)^2\cos xdx$$

$$=\int_0^1 u^7(1-u^2)^2 du (\text{ Putting }\sin x=u)$$

$$=\int_0^1 (u^7-2u^9+u^{11}) du$$

$$=\left(\frac{u^8}8-2\frac{u^{10}}{10}+\frac{u^{12}}{12}\right)_0^1$$

$$=\frac18-\frac15+\frac1{12}$$

$$=\frac{15-24+10}{120}=\frac1{120} $$

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to integrate between step $(5)$ and $(6)$! $$\int_0^1 \left(u^7-2u^9+u^{11}\right)\ du \quad =\quad \left(\frac{u^8}{8}  -\frac{u^{10}}{5}   + \frac{u^{12}}{12}\right)\Big|_0^1 = \frac 18 - \frac 15 +\frac 1{12} = \frac 1{120}$$

You're work was fine, otherwise (you left out $\,dx$ from your earlier integrals, and the factor $\cos x$, which turns out to be $\,du$ and so accommodated in the substitution in the second step), but I think your primary lapse was simply forgetting to *integrate* before evaluating ;-)

Comment: thanks definititely sloppy in my handwriting. but you are absolutely right i forgot to take the integral. Long day thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, Miguel!

Comment: @amWhy: Looks good to me +1

Answer (score 6):

Another approach using $$\frac{m! n!}{(m+n+1)!}=\operatorname{B}(m+1,n+1)=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2m+1}x\sin^{2n+1}x \, dx.$$

In our case $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^7x \cos^5x \, dx=\frac{\operatorname{B}(3,4)}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2! 3!}{6!}=\frac{1}{120}.$$

Here $\operatorname{B}$ denotes [Beta function.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html)

Comment: this seems like a clever solution unfortunately i dont understand it but i would definitely study this a little more.

Answer (score 2):

step 6 is wrong, check it again, it should be $$\frac{u^8}{8} + \frac{u^{12}}{12} - \frac{u^{10} }{5}$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to show you a general method for integrals like this.

Consider the integral
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^ax\ \cos^bx\ dx$$
$t=\sin^2x$:

$\therefore dt=2\sin x\cos x\ dx\\\therefore dx=\frac12t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}dt\\\therefore x=0\mapsto t=0\\\therefore x=\pi/2\mapsto t=1$
$$I(a,b)=\int_0^1 t^{a/2}(1-t)^{b/2}\frac12t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{-1/2}dt$$
$$I(a,b)=\frac12\int_0^1 t^{\frac{a-1}2}(1-t)^{\frac{b-1}2}dt$$
$$I(a,b)=\frac12\int_0^1 t^{\frac{a+1}2-1}(1-t)^{\frac{b+1}2-1}dt$$
Note the definition of the Beta function:
$$B(a,b)=\int_0^1t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}=B(b,a)$$
Thus
$$I(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{a+1}2)\Gamma(\frac{b+1}2)}{2\Gamma(\frac{a+b}2+1)}=I(b,a)$$
Where $\Gamma(x)$ is the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^7 x \cos ^5 x & \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{=} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos ^5 x \sin ^7 x d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^5 x\cos ^5 x\left(\sin ^2 x+\cos ^2 x\right) d x \\
&=\frac{1}{64} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^5(2 x)d x \\
&=\frac{1}{128} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left(1-\cos ^2 2 x\right)^2 d(\cos 2 x) \\
&=\frac{1}{128}\left[\cos 2 x-\frac{2 \cos ^3 2 x}{3}+\frac{\cos ^5 2 x}{5}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{120}
\end{aligned}
$$